# How to print dataframe difference result in row format

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

**Problem Statement**:
**Edited as per comments :**

1 ) I have two json files which comes from different sources and I am converting to df and using numpy to compare and tell the difference as yes or no if there is difference in values

2. And the json files are dynamic in such way that, there might some columns which are matching in both df and some of the columns will be missing on any side (i.e means full outer join). so means both df may have a common column to compare and may be a column name which is not exist on other side.
3. for example in below sample json files, df_a does not have Fare column and df_b has it

df_a from json:

```
[
    {
        "FlightNo": "12345",
        "Airlines": "Delta"                 
    }
]
```

df_b from json :

```
[
    {
        "FlightNo": "12345",
        "Airlines": "Delta",        
        "Fare" : "4500"         
    }
]
```

What I tried:
4) if column names in both df_a and df_b are known in hand, then i am writing thing specifally with column names for comparing

```
    df1 = pd.merge(df_a[['FlightNo']],df_b[['FlightNo']],left_index=True,right_index=True)
    df1['diff'] = np.where((df1['FlightNo_x']==df1['FlightNo_y']),'No', 'Yes') 
        
       
    df2 = pd.merge(df_a[['Airlines']],df_b[['Airlines']],left_index=True,right_index=True)
    df2['diff'] = np.where((df2['Airlines_x']==df2['Airlines_y']),'No', 'Yes')

    df3 = pd.merge(df_a[['Fare']],df_b[['Fare']],left_index=True,right_index=True)
        df2['diff'] = np.where((df2['Fare_x']==df2['Fare_y']),'No', 'Yes')
```

5)Current output: (third line is difference between in row1 and row 2 values)

```
     FlightNo_x Flightno_y   Diff 
     12345      Delta        No
    
     Airlines_x Airlines_y   Diff
     Delta      Delta        No  

     Fare_x     Fare_y       Diff
     NaN        4500         Yes
```

6. now the challenge is the column called Fare do not exist in first df_a and is there in df_b so i cannot hard code column name to comepare, there is chance that df_b can have more than one new columns which wont be there in df_a.
7. so is there is way to tell pandas , i dont specify column name for each comparison like above, program should calculate all the available columns by some means compare it and produce the difference as yes or No
8. based on point number 7 is there a way to output in below format( but I am fine with any format of output like above mentioned in point no 5 or below

[image]

Comment: how row3 `no no Yes` came?

Comment: i am writing some thing like this , but it priting Yes or No as new column, as its comparing x and y in columnar format, but i wanted is that possible to row wise put difference in row ..df1 = pd.merge(df_a[['FlightNo']],df_b[['FlightNo']],left_index=True,right_index=True)
df1['diff'] = np.where((df1['FlightNo_x']==df1['FlightNo_y']),'No', 'Yes')

Comment: and also is there any way to tell pandas to do the comparision without mentioning column name while merging...assuming that these two source dataframes are generated by other process, where i dont know how many columns are there in both dataframes and i need to compare these unknown number of colums in dataframe.. if i know there defenite columns i can merge based on column names but if columns names are dynamic and some are common columns and some are unknow new columns, there is challenge to compare., as outerjoin needs a key to do the outer join. Need expert suggestion pls

Comment: Can you update your question as per the how the you want to generate your output. It will help others to look into it.

Comment: sure shall do that

Comment: updated question and requirements more clear...hope its better explanation what i am trying to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this, with `transpose()` and `np.where()`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as  np
data=[
    {
        "FlightNo": "12345",
        "Airlines": "Delta"                 
    }
]


data2=[
    {
        "FlightNo": "12345",
        "Airlines": "Delta",        
        "Fare" : "4500"         
    }
]
df1=pd.DataFrame(data)
df2=pd.DataFrame(data2)
print(df1)
df=pd.concat([df1,df2],ignore_index=True).transpose()
df[2]=np.where(df[0]==df[1],'No','Yes')
df=df.T
print(df)
```

Output:

```
df
      FlightNo Airlines  Fare
    0    12345    Delta   NaN
    1    12345    Delta  4500
    2       No       No   Yes
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming, you are able to get the JSON's into one dataframe, then you could do something like the following.,

input:

```
    FlightNo    Airlines    Fare
0   12345       Delta       Nan
1   12345       Delta       4500
```

code (loop through the columns and assign values to a new dataframe and then append):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'FlightNo' : ['1'], 'Airlines' : ['2'], 'Fare' : ['3']})
for i in range(len(df.columns)):
    if df.iloc[0,i-1] == df.iloc[1,i-1]:
        df1.iloc[0,i-1] = 'No'
    else:
        df1.iloc[0,i-1] = 'Yes'
df = df.append(df1)
df
```

output:

```
    FlightNo    Airlines    Fare
0   12345       Delta       Nan
1   12345       Delta       4500
0   No          No          Yes
```